# How to fix intellisense for VS2010 if VS2012 changed files in bin folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I currently work with projects using VS2010, but my colleagues use VS2012 and one of my colleagues updated the bin folder for an SVN repo and changed files that affected my intellisense. I've tried creating a new MVC 4 project and overwriting the following files:

- System.Web.Optimization.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
- WebGrease.dll

But unfortunately, my intellisense still isn't working. Are there additional files that I should be taking into account?

Comment: Which IntelliSense isn't working? What happens? What do you see in the Output Window?

Comment: Just my intellisense for model binding and Viewbag accessing in Razor views/HTML. I don't get any build errors, just squiggly lines under the model and viewbags that say: The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the solution?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried rebuilding, which only temporarily makes the squiggle errors go away, but if I try and type something that uses the model or Viewbag data, they come back and I'm still unable to access them.